# Making the navbar transparent

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a navbar. There are 2 tabs. They have 2 images instead of text. This however makes the image display in the center and a padding present in the tab. 
How can I make this tab transparent so that only the image is made to appear?

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" role="navigation" class="ui-navbar ui-mini" >  
    <img style="max-height:90%; max-width:100%;" src="Header_image.jpg" alt="image"/>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="HolidayList.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"><img style="max-height:90%; max-width:100%;"  src="holiday_list_btn.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="ClosedLocations.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"><img style="max-height:90%; max-width:100%;"  src="Closed_location_btn.png"/><!--CLOSED LOCATIONS--></a></li>         
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following bits of CSS to the `<img>` styling of each image:

```
padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: block;
```

So—using your example—it looks like this:

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" role="navigation" class="ui-navbar ui-mini" >  
    <img style="max-height:90%; max-width:100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: block;" src="Header_image.jpg" alt="image"/>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="HolidayList.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"><img style="max-height:90%; max-width:100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: block;"  src="holiday_list_btn.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="ClosedLocations.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"><img style="max-height:90%; max-width:100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: block;"  src="Closed_location_btn.png"/><!--CLOSED LOCATIONS--></a></li>         
    </ul>
</div>
```

But why not do this with separated CSS in the header or loaded via an external file?

```
img {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
}
```

Doing it this way will better utilize CSS since code will not have to be repeated for each image & can be managed by one CSS definition.

And in general I would recommend you have a CSS rule that affects all elements like this:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Nope. Not working. I feel its a property of the navbar that we have to change.

Comment: Nope still the same thing. :(

Comment: Nope, the external css also didnt help. Any property of the navbar itself?

Comment: try adding css property  background as transparent